# Low quality posts queue: system shows actual number of votes when checks reviewer attention

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, low-quality-posts

As we all know, sometimes we're being tested - if we're paying attention - when we review low quality posts. The system can give us a high-quality post and expect us to click "Looks good".

My suggestion is to hide actual votes done on this post. Right now I see the real number of votes (which is usually high) this question/answer has which makes this test almost useless.

Comment: From what I have read in the past, the audit it suppose to be relatively obvious. I think this is [status-by-design]. [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225870/showing-votes-on-review-audit-questions) is relevant.. it was marked [status-by-design].

Comment: @JoshCrozier Can you please post a link/reference/whatever you read about the simplicity of the audit? I'd like to read it too. While I agree that it should be easy, IMO it is too obvious. But, if its purpose is solely bot-protection, it is just fine then.

Comment: See: [Review Audits are too obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178193/close-vote-review-audits-are-too-obvious), [Audit has shown too much detail about the post making the audit obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185982/audit-has-shown-too-much-detail-about-the-post-making-the-audit-obvious), and [Showing votes on review audit questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225870/showing-votes-on-review-audit-questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *Josh Crozier* correctly pointed, the audits are designed to distingush between human and bot reviewer. DEATH TO ALL HUMANS! (Sorry, couldn't stop myself). That's why they're easy to detect for reviewer that paying at least minimal attention before making his choice.